# PHP preg_match_all remove url parameters on the fly

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to fetch only the 'cleaner' version of the url without any parameters.
IOW... if there is a question mark inside the url remove it and everything afterwards.

Here is my current line :

```
preg_match_all('/<a(.*?)href=("|\'|)(.*?)("|\'| )(.*?)>/s',$content,$ahref);
```

And just to be more clear here... I'm expecting that this url (for example):

```
/go/page/mobile_download_apps.html?&who=r,6GDewh28SCW3/fUSqmWqR_E9ljkcH1DheIMqgbiHjlX3OBDbskcuCZ22iDvk0zeZR7BEthcEaXGFWaQ4Burmd4eKuhMpqojjDE6BrCiUtLClkT32CejpMIdnqVOUmWBD
```

Would be :

```
/go/page/mobile_download_apps.html
```

Comment: Wouldn't this do the trick ? `/(<a href=")(.*)(\?.*)/s` (missing some info to give a more detailed answer...)

Comment: @Benoît Yes it would. But only in this example, not for other cases, e.g. when `?` was absent. (And OP will just keep reasking those regex questions without trying to understand what they do.)

Comment: The best way to go is to get the url using some DOM parser, then use regex to remove that trailing part... ie: getting everything till the first `?` => https://regex101.com/r/mD3sB1/1

Comment: This is very easy to remove everything after the ? but I was asking if it's possible to do it on the fly directly via regex

Comment: @Enissay Completely remove it...  (no need to capture)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aO1uU3/2

Comment: Why not using http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With DOMDocument, strpos, substr:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$linkNodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($linkNodeList as $linkNode) {
    $href = $linkNode->getAttribute('href');

    if ( false !== ($offset = strpos($href, '?')) )
        $linkNode->setAttribute('href', substr($href, 0, $offset));
}

$newContent = $dom->saveHTML();
```

or with explode:

```
$linkNode->setAttribute('href', explode('?', $href)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this behavior:

```
<a\s+href\s*=\s*"\K[^"?]+


$result = preg_replace('/<a\s+href\s*=\s*"\K[^"?]+/im', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't get the tag with regex, you should use a parser. Nevertheless, here you go:

```
<a[^>]+href=("|')([^"'?]*)[^"']*\1[^>]*>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tV5pP8/3

Comment: Backreferences `[^\1]` don't work in character classes.

Answer (score -1):

Opps... Lack of concentration from my side :)

Solved it by myself... (It was super easy)

Here is the final line :

```
preg_match_all('/<a(.*?)href=("|\'|)(.*?)(\?|"|\'| )(.*?)>/s',$content,$ahref);
```